# Loading content from all combinations of two drop-boxes using selenium and phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I have a job I want to automate through Selenium and HhantomJS using Python 2.7 bindings. The problem is that the website I am trying to automate has two dropboxes. The first dropbox loads the content of the second dropbox, and the second dropbox in turn loads the content on the website.

I want to get all combinations of this. So i wrote the following code:

```
with contextlib.closing(webdriver.PhantomJS(phantomjs)) as driver:
driver.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
firstmenu = driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$Body$Browse1$ddlFosList");
firstmenuoptions = firstmenu.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
firstmenuoptionsiter =iter(firstmenuoptions)
next(firstmenuoptionsiter)
for firstmenuoption in firstmenuoptionsiter:
    firstmenuoption.click()
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$Body$Browse1$ddlFosList"))
    secondmenu = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_Body_Browse1_ddlCourseBlockList")
    secondmenuoptions = secondmenu.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
    for secondmenuoption in secondmenuoptions:
        print secondmenuoption.text
```

However, im getting a StaleElementReference exception at the print secondmenuoption.text line. This is probably because the page reloads when the first menu is selected. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: If you reselect the element, the Exception should go away (after each refresh)

Comment: Reselecting it wont really help me though. I need to get all combinations of the dropdowns options. In fact, reselecting does make the exception go away, but prints blank lines now

Comment: I think the information in this link might prove helpful for what you're trying to do: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver

Comment: Richard, I did not find anything that answered my query. Regarding the staleElementReference exception

Answer (score 0):

I've had some problems with StaleElementReference exceptions, and the best solution I can come up with is adding Thread.sleep(). You can't wait for some expected condition because all elements in the second dropbox would have already been loaded.

Selenium does have the function refreshed(ExpectedCondition condition), so you can give that a try. Otherwise, I think the Thread.sleep() is a working (but bad) solution.

Comment: Adding sleep doesnt work. The problem is whenever I click on any option in the first box, the page refreshes(to fill in the second box). This causes the StaleException to arise, because the reference to the first dropdown is lost after the refresh. 

Now if I try to reassign the first dropdown, my outer loop gets screwed! What to do!